# Serializing to JSON in asp.net?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json

Hi am using JSON for the firsttime in asp.net

I have my WebMethod like this

```
               [WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string Vo_Get(string Action,int ID)
{
    Product p= new Product();

    DataSet ds= new DataSet();

    p.Action = Action;
    p.ID= ID;

    ds= VoGet_Get(obj);

    **string jsonVesselDetails = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds, Formatting.None);
    return jsonVesselDetails;**
}
```

here iam getting my result as

```
       [
  {
    "Pinky": 1,
    "Ponky": "Breakwater Dockk",

  },
  {
    "Pinky": 2,
    "Ponky": "Watson Island Dock",    
  },
```

But when i tried to call using Ajax and append to table its giving Unexpexted Token U if i try to bind with result and its giving Unexpected token O if i try to bind with result.data

Finally i found problem is with serialization,

my Ajax call is

```
                  $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Voyage.aspx/Vo_Get",
                data: "{'Action':'Get','ID':'68'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    try {
                        alert("getdata! success" );

                        Get(data);

                    } catch (ex) {
                        alert(ex);
                    }
                },
                error: function (msg) {
                    alert("err: " + error);
                }
            });
```

and

Comment: see the response in firebug, it might result something like d. Coz, asp.net round the json result with "d" which is a type of jsonp(JSON with Padding) just for security reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you are using the same variable `data` in success function as well. 
Try using the following,

```
success: function (result) {
   try {
        alert("getdata! success" );

        GetVessels(result);

        //Rebuild the table
        //BuildVesselTaggerInfo();

   } catch (ex) {
        alert(ex);
   }
},
```

note that I have changed from data to result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what GetVessels is expecting but try:

```
GetVessels(data.d);
```

i.e. pass the actual data rather than the entire response object.

Comment: Yes when i give like these also its not working, its giving error

Answer (score 0):

First of all verify what kind of `JSON` or array structure your `GetVessles` method expects.

you can do it by directly feeding the JSON response of `VoyageVessel_Get` method or construct it manually. i.e.

```
 var data= [
 {
      "TerminalID": 1,
      "TerminalName": "Breakwater Dockk",
      "PortID": 1,
      "PortName": "Swire Pacific Offshore",
      "Column1": "08/03/13",
      "Column2": "16/03/13",
      "ServiceID": 2
  },
  {
      "TerminalID": 2,
      "TerminalName": "Watson Island Dock",
      "PortID": 2,
      "PortName": "Keppel Offshore",
      "Column1": "20/03/13",
      "Column2": "23/03/13",
      "ServiceID": 2
  }];

  GetVessels(data);
```

see if your `GetVessels` works for this object. if it doesn't then find out what structure it needs(only you can do that), and construct that.

Second, you cannot access directly the response of `:success` in `ASP.NET Web-Service`.

access it like this:

```
success: function (data) {
           var jsonData= data.d;
           GetVessels(jsonData);
 }
```

## update

if your object consist of datetime field try specifying DateFormathandling in the `Serialization` i.e.

```
JsonSerializerSettings microsoftDateFormatSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat
            };
string serializedObject= Newtonsoft.Json
                     .JsonConvert
                     .SerializeObject(dsVoyages, microsoftDateFormatSettings);
```

Comment: Is my WebMethod Serialization in correct format..., i hope that must be changed, as iam getting prob there

Comment: yeah, it looks ok. do you get any error upon serialization? i mean before return statement? I also see a datetime field in your dataset, try to specify DateFormatHandling. wait m updating my code